# Flutter BottomNavigationBar with transparent background

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm trying to build a BottomNavigationBar and Float Action Button that has no background (transparent)
[Layout sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaI20.png)
Could you guys help to layout for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the background extend under the BottomNavigationBar You should set:

```
extendBody: true
```

as a property in BottomNavigationBar.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap the bottom navigation bar with theme widget and try to modify canvas color property to transparent something looks like below

```
child: Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context)
              .copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
)
```